# Counting from multiple Columns in SAS

Tags: database, sas

I have 24 columns that list a code (code1, code2, code3 etc). I need to calculate a total frequency of codes from all 24 columns (from greatest to least). I tried creating separate files for each and then doing a proc freq but it only used that last file entered.

Comment: You need to specify which data set to use with the DATA= option in PROC FREQ.  If you do not specify a data set, SAS defaults to the last one created.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin this beast.  I would use an array in a Data Step to create 1 column out of 24.  Then do what you will with it (PROC FREQ, or whatever).

This assumes your 24 columns are named, col1, col2, ... , col24.

```
data want;
set have;
array cols[24] col1 - col24; /*here list your columns*/
format code $32.; /*change size as needed*/

do i=1 to 24;
   code = cols[i];
   output;
end;

drop i col1 - col24; /*put your unneeded column names here*/
run;
```